# Como activar y desactivar un slider en Matlab

Tags: matlab

Anexo código que intente donde name es una imagen que estoy tratando de cargar para su procesamiento.

```
 [name,path]=uigetfile;
                if name == 0
                    app.GammaSlider,'Enable';
                    app.ContrasteSlider,'Enable';
                    app.BrilloSlider,'Enable';
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad 'Enable' del objeto del slider, supongamos que tienes tres sliders en tu interfaz gráfica de usuario (GUI) de MATLAB llamados GammaSlider, ContrasteSlider y BrilloSlider. Puedes habilitar o deshabilitar estos sliders utilizando la propiedad 'Enable'Para habilitar un slider, puedes establecer la propiedad 'Enable' en 'on', y para deshabilitarlo, puedes establecerla en 'off
Ejem:

```
[name, path] = uigetfile;

if name == 0
    set(app.GammaSlider, 'Enable', 'on');
    set(app.ContrasteSlider, 'Enable', 'on');
    set(app.BrilloSlider, 'Enable', 'on');
end
```